# How to straighten skewed ggplot2 map with raster data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, map-projections

When plotting my map of NLCD tree canopy data (a raster), the map is not straight or aligned with the map border. The skew seems to occur when using the projectRaster function. Is there a way to adjust the raster to be level and even with the border? When running the code below/looking at the uploaded image, the skew that I would like to remove is the dark grey uneven border while having the tree data fill the entire frame. I have been unable to find any solutions to this, so I appreciate any advice!

Picture of skew: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPhZI.jpg)

```
library(sf)
#devtools::install_github("ropensci/FedData")
library(FedData)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(RColorBrewer)

ext <- extent(734666.5, 795961.6, 4017870, 4053632)

extent <- polygon_from_extent(raster::extent(ext), proj4string='+proj=utm +datum=NAD83 +zone=16N')

WMAtc <- get_nlcd(template = polygon_from_extent(ext, (proj4string = "+proj=utm +zone=16N ellps+NAD83")), year = 2016, dataset = "Tree_Canopy", label = "Can", force.redo = T) 

WMAtc_projected <- projectRaster(WMAtc, crs = "+proj=utm +zone=16N +datum=NAD83") 

tc_df <- as.data.frame(WMAtc_projected, xy=TRUE) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_raster(data = tc_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill=tc_df[,3])) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(8, "Greens"), name = "Tree Canopy Cover")
```

Answer (score 0):

A professor graciously helped me fix the problem. With his code you can see where the extent bounding box is in relation to the downloaded NLCD data. When projected, the NLCD data is adjusted and extended past the original extent. To fix this, you can crop the extra data and it will realign the imagery of your maps.

```
library(FedData)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(sf)

ext <- extent(734666.5, 795961.6, 4017870, 4053632)

extent <- polygon_from_extent(raster::extent(ext), proj4string='+proj=utm +datum=NAD83 +zone=16N')

WMAtc <- get_nlcd(template = polygon_from_extent(ext, (proj4string = "+proj=utm +zone=16N ellps+NAD83")),year = 2016, dataset = "Tree_Canopy", label = "Can")

WMAtc_projected <- projectRaster(WMAtc, crs = "+proj=utm +zone=16N +datum=NAD83")

tc_df <- as.data.frame(WMAtc_projected, xy=TRUE)

ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = tc_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill=tc_df[,3])) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(8, "Greens"), name = "Tree Canopy Cover") +
  geom_sf(data=st_as_sf(extent), fill=NA, col="red") # show desired raster extent

WMAtc_projected_cropped = crop(WMAtc_projected, extent) #crop to remove extra bits
tc_df_cropped <- as.data.frame(WMAtc_projected_cropped, xy=TRUE)

ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = tc_df_cropped, aes(x = x, y = y, fill=tc_df_cropped[,3])) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(8, "Greens"), name = "Tree Canopy Cover") +
  geom_sf(data=st_as_sf(extent), fill=NA, col="red")
```